# Can I access the Sharepoint 2013 event model without enabling application sideloading?

Tags: development, 2013, event-receivers

Note: originally posted on stackoverflow, just registered here.

My goal is to initiate some custom processing external to our Sharepoint 2013 installation when a document is added to a specific document library.  I am primarily a Java programmer tackling my first Sharepoint/.net effort.  Let me detail what I've tried so far.

My initial research led me to event receivers developed with the SSOM model.  This won't work for us, as I don't have access to develop on the actual Sharepoint server, and we don't want to use the SSOM model.

I then tried using Sharepoint Designer to create a Sharepoint workflow to initiate action when a new document is added.  My boss (the farm owner and admin) has previous experience with Sharepoint workflows.  He doesn't consider them stable, so this option is out.

I then found the concept of a Remote Event Receiver, and developed a visual studio project based on this URL: http://blog.johnnyt.me/2013/07/adventures-with-sharepoint-2013-remote-event-receivers-part-1/

This seemed to be what I was looking for.  When I tried to run the project, I believe the RER is installed as a Sharepoint "App", and I get the following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site.
```

The solution to this appears unanimous, enabling sideloading for sharepoint: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2013/02/04/quot-sideloading-of-apps-is-not-enabled-on-this-site-quot.aspx

However, my boss isn't comfortable enabling this until he knows more about it.

Is there any other way for me to tap into sharepoint document events besides what I've already tried?

Thanks.